# Dynamically Show / Hide dive using its ID

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a one PHP page which have one link Add Form.onclick of this link it will add a one new form with a remove form button.now i want to assign a unique id to each new form wrapper and on the basis of that i will remove the form from the page.

JS Code:-

```
function addLinkFrom() 
{
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'linkform';
div.innerHTML = '<label class="linklabel">Add Link: </label><input type="text" id="txtaddlink" name="txtaddlink[]" class="expfield" placeholder="Enter Link"/>\
    <div class="clearboth"></div>\
    <input type="button" class="btn linkpad btn-primary" value="Remove" onclick="removeLinkForm(this)">\
    <div class="line"></div>';
    document.getElementById('addlinkform').appendChild(div);
}

function removeLinkForm(input) 
{
 alert("Remove Link");      
 document.getElementById('addlinkform').removeChild( input.parentNode );
}
```

HTML Code:-

```
<a onClick="return addLinkFrom();">Add Link</a>
```

So now how i will assaign a new ID to wrapper when i am click on Add Link.If you have any solution then plases share it with me.

Comment: Where is the form itself?

Comment: I mean one field i.e <input type="text" id="txtaddlink" name="txtaddlink[]" class="expfield" placeholder="Enter Link"/>\

Comment: Why do you want to do it by ID? Your function should already work,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a running sequence. Just add a `var suffix = 0;` before the functions, and then append that to a generic prefix for the wrapper id.

Comment: But it will automatically increase the value or not?

Comment: Not on its own, but you can increment the value in the same `addLinkFrom()` function.